# Can't scroll on autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/T7KGK/1/) is my code :

## HTML

```
<input type="textbox" id="txtComune" />
<div id="myOwnMenuComuni" style="position:absolute; top:0; left:0px; height:1px;"></div>
```

## CSS

```
.ui-widget-content a 
{
    color: #222222 !important;
    cursor: pointer !important;
    float: left !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
}  

#myOwnMenuComuni .ui-autocomplete 
{
    width: 200px !important;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

## jQuery

```
var listaComuni = ["Abbiategrasso","Acireale","Acquaviva Delle","Acqui Terme","Adelfia","Adrano","Adria","Adro","Agnosine"];

$('#txtComune').autocomplete({
    source: listaComuni,        
    appendTo: "#myOwnMenuComuni"
});​
```

try to select input, insert "a", and select the last item : it is impossible. Why? And how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed removing `float:left` with `display:block`

Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 1):

If I uncheck "normalize CSS" and link to the jQuery UI CSS then it works fine:
**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T7KGK/3/)**

Comment: yeah, ok, but I need to style my own autocomplete menu! So, how?